# Blazor:Cannot implicitly convert type 'Starter.PostModels.Post[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Starter.UI.Services.BlogPost>' [Starter]"

Tags: c#, rest, blazor

I am trying to connect a new Blazor app I have to a REST API created through Django. However I am unable to create the services file as it appears with the error. How should I change BlogPost.cs so that it connects to the API?

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Starter.PostModels.Post[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Starter.UI.Services.BlogPost>' [Starter]"

**Starter/Services/BlogPost.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Json;

namespace Starter.UI.Services
{
    public class BlogPost : IBlogPost
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        
        public BlogPost(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<BlogPost>> GetPosts()
        {
            return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Post[]>("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/");
        }
    }
}
```

**Starter/Services/IBlogPost.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Starter.UI.Services
{
    public interface IBlogPost
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<BlogPost>> GetPosts();
    }
}
```

**Starter/Models/Post.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Starter.PostModels
{
    public class Post
    {
        public string title { get; set; } = default!;
        public string author { get; set; } = default!;
        public string content { get; set; } = default!;
        public string status { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}
```

**Starter/Pages/Blog.razor**

```
@page "/blog"
@using Starter.PostModels'
@using Starter.UI.Services
@inject IBlogPost GetPosts;

<h1>Blog Posts</h1>

@code{
    private IEnumerable<Post> Data = null;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedASync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        Data = await IBlogPost.GetPosts();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to Post[] to a IEnumerable

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<BlogPost>> GetPosts()
{
    return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Post[]>("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/");
}
```

Try this

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Post>> GetPosts()
{
    return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Post>>("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/");
}
```